# Почему вылетает exception при десериализации?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Есть класс :

```
    [Serializable]
    public class UserAccount
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public PasswordBox Password { get; set; }

        public UserAccount(string _name, string _surname, string _login, PasswordBox _password)
        {
            Name = _name;
            Surname = _surname;
            Login = _login;
            Password = _password;
        } 
    }
```

Метод десериализации:

```
        public void Deserialize()
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("..\\..\\Accounts.dat", FileMode.Open);
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                listUsers = (List<UserAccount>)formatter.Deserialize(fs);//вылетает exception
                fs.Close();
            }

            catch
            {
                listUsers = new List<UserAccount>();
            }
        }
```

Ошибка:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>        Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Gallery.ViewModels.LoginViewModel' that matches the specified
>   binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '15' and line
>   position '10'.

**Update**

```
public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private List<UserAccount> listUsers;

        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            _currentName = String.Empty;
            _currentSurname = String.Empty;
            _currentLogin = String.Empty;
            _currentPasswordBox = new PasswordBox();
            Deserialize();
        }
        private string _currentSurname;

        public string CurrentSurname
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentSurname;
            }
            set
            {
                _currentSurname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _currentName;

        public string CurrentName
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentName;
            }
            set
            {
                _currentName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _currentLogin;

        public string CurrentLogin
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentLogin;
            }
            set
            {
                _currentLogin = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private PasswordBox _currentPasswordBox;

        public PasswordBox currentPassword
        {
            get { return _currentPasswordBox; }
            set
            {
                _currentPasswordBox = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private RegistrationCheckCommand checkReg;
        public ICommand ButtonClick
        {
            get { return checkReg ?? (checkReg = new RegistrationCheckCommand(o => AddNewAccount())); }
        }

        private void AddNewAccount()
        {
            UserAccount user = new UserAccount(CurrentName, CurrentSurname, CurrentLogin, currentPassword);
            listUsers.Add(user);
            Serialize();
            MessageBox.Show("Account adding!");
        }

        public void Serialize()
        {

            try
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("..\\..\\Accounts.dat", FileMode.Create);
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(fs, listUsers);
                fs.Close();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        public void Deserialize()
        {
            //try
            //{
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("..\\..\\Accounts.dat", FileMode.Open);
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                listUsers = (List<UserAccount>)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
                fs.Close();
            //}

            //catch
            //{
            //    listUsers = new List<UserAccount>();
            //}
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


    }
```

Xaml

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Gallery.LoginWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Gallery.ViewModels"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Login window" TitleCaps="False" Height="433.735" Width="300.803"
                  ResizeMode="NoResize"
                  BorderBrush="White">


<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <local:LoginViewModel x:Key="LoginWindow"/>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>

<Controls:MetroAnimatedTabControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" DataContext="{StaticResource LoginWindow}">
    <Controls:MetroTabItem Header="Sign In">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="Login" Foreground="White" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Name="login" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text="Password" Foreground="White" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
            <PasswordBox Name="pass" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"></PasswordBox>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}"
                    Margin="0,20,0,0" Content="sign in"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=login}">
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Controls:MetroTabItem>
    <Controls:MetroTabItem Header="Registration">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="Login" Foreground="White" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Name="regLogin" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text="Password" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" ></TextBlock>
            <PasswordBox  Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"></PasswordBox>
            <TextBlock Text="Name" Foreground="White" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Name="regName" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Text="Surname" Foreground="White" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Name="regSurname" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"></TextBox>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}"
                    Margin="0,20,0,0" Content="Register" Command="{Binding ButtonClick }">
                <Button.IsEnabled>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RegistrationFormConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="regLogin" Path="Text.Length" />
                        <Binding ElementName="regName" Path="Text.Length"  />
                        <Binding ElementName="regSurname" Path="Text.Length"  />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Button.IsEnabled>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Controls:MetroTabItem>
</Controls:MetroAnimatedTabControl>
```

StackTrace

> at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
>   handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean
>   isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream)
>
> at Gallery.ViewModels.LoginViewModel.Deserialize() in
>   C:\Users\Константин\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Gallery\Gallery\ViewModels\LoginViewModel.cs:line
>   121

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35915/discussion-on-question-by-lightness---exception--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените тип данного свойства

```
    public PasswordBox Password { get; set; }
```

на `string` или любой другой тип, не являющийся коллекцией и помеченный как сериализуемый.

`PasswordBox` - контрол, контролы не сериализуются с помощью стандартных сериализоторов, т.к. являются рекурсивной коллекцией, т.е. любой контрол содержит коллекцию дочерних котролов, пустую или нет - неважно.

После изменений, удалите файл данных, повторите сериализацию и десериализацию.

С ограничениями может быть использован специальный сериализатор либо ручная сериализация.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему у вас ошибка возникает из-за Accounts.dat
Попробуйте создать новый .dat следующим методом

```
public void Serialize() 
{ 
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("..\\..\\Accounts.dat", FileMode.Create);
    try
    {           
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(fs, listUsers);
    }
    finally 
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Проверка сериализации в файл и десериализации из файла также работает без ошибок.

```
[Serializable]
public class PasswordBox 
{
}

[Serializable]
public class UserAccount 
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }
   public string Login { get; set; }
   public PasswordBox Password { get; set; }

   public UserAccount(string _name, string _surname, string _login, PasswordBox _password) 
   {
       Name = _name;
       Surname = _surname;
       Login = _login;
       Password = _password;
   }    
}

void Main() {
    List<UserAccount> listUsers = new List<UserAccount>();
    listUsers.Add(new UserAccount("n", "s", "l", new PasswordBox()));
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    FileStream fs1 = new FileStream("..\\..\\Accounts.dat", FileMode.Create);
    try
    {           
        formatter.Serialize(fs1, listUsers);
    }
    finally 
    {
        fs1.Close();
    }

    FileStream fs2 = new FileStream("..\\..\\Accounts.dat", FileMode.Open);
    try 
    {
        listUsers = (List<UserAccount>) formatter.Deserialize(fs2);
    }
    finally 
    { 
        fs2.Close();
    }

    listUsers.Dump();       
}
```